# Flags aged away

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flagging

Some of my post flags were aged away, and I wanted to re-flag them. However, the options of the standard ones were not available, and so my only choice is to use "moderator attention" flags. But such flags were declined because they were not standard flags. In one of the instances, I even specifically stated that a previous flag aged away. What should I have done? Maybe we should re-allow the options to use standard flags if the flags aged away?

***A bigger problem is that my flags are declined based on the fact that I reflagged, not on the actual quality of the questions.***

Attached is an image of what happened:

[image]

**Edit 1/19:
It happened again.**
[image]

**Edit 1/25 Last time I'll update this question, but it happened again and will probably not stop happening**
[image]
Also the problem was closed after I flagged it, so IDK about what's happening.

Comment: You may find useful the background information about the mechanism for close flags to "age away" in the previous post [How avoid aged away flags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25712/how-avoid-aged-away-flags).

Comment: According to this [Meta StackExchange post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266501/cant-re-flag-aged-away-flag) you should be able to recast a close vote or reflag after your vote/flag has aged away.  So it sounds like this is a regression bug.

Comment: @hardmath apparently there is still a bug that doesn't allow me to do so.

Comment: I'm confused by the image above, which shows both Questions as `[closed]`.  Is it possible that you are unable to flag for closing... because these are already closed?

Comment: @hardmath They were not closed when I re-flagged them.

Comment: I looked at the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3924204/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries) for the second Question.  Not all information was there (and it now seems to have been deleted), but it's possible that the close review was "invalidated" without your flag aging out.  See the previous meta Question [What clears a low-quality flag and what removes a review from the LQ queue?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27559/what-clears-a-low-quality-flag-and-what-removes-a-review-from-the-lq-queue)  The first Question also seems to be deleted.

Comment: @hardmath "cast a close vote or reflag..." i have "aged away" flags which i can't reflag.